# iOS 11-13 - unable to paste into comments

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app, paste

I’m able to copy-paste from any application to any application. I’m able to copy from a comment or from a question or from an answer. I’m able to paste to a question or answer. However, if I attempt to paste into a comment, nothing happens. I am able to subsequently paste into another application, confirming that the text is actually on the clipboard.

However, copying SE links will paste them successfully, but all other text - including other links - still fails. This leads me to believe that it’s a SE issue and not an Apple one.

This has been an issue since 11.0 beta and persists through iOS 13 release.

Comment: Reproduced on an iPad Pro running iOS 11 Beta.

Comment: iOS 11 **Beta**?

Comment: @iBug Yes, beta. Hence the first paragraph of my post.

Comment: Seeing this on latest iOS 11 beta (using the beta version of the SE app.)

Comment: How did you test it? For instance I can drag-n-drop links and text from the Chrome into the SE app comment section in Split View mode.

Comment: @alexolut I didn’t say drag and drop. I said copy and paste: highlight text, then tap “copy,” then tap into a comment field and tap “paste.” (Like I said in the OP - I’m on an iPhone and therefore don’t have drag and drop.)

Comment: @DonielF oh, now I see. Upvoted!

Comment: Reproduced in 11.0.1 release iPhone 6S. I can paste the copied text into other apps

Comment: I can reproduce it: can’t paste into comments anything that is not a SE link after the update to iOS 11 on iPhone

Comment: Reproduced. iOS 11.0.6, iPhone 6. **When I paste into answers, the original font style, spacing and font size get preserved, it looks pretty horrible and doesn’t affect markdown.**

Comment: Reproduced on 11.2 beta. Updated to reflect that.

Comment: Any chance of fixing this annoying and long standing issue?

Comment: @mplungjan no, the app development has been frozen, the only iOS developer reassigned to different role within Stack Overflow. We won't see this fixed in the near future. (That is, years.)

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard This bug has existed for a long time now, so I'm just wondering if your last comment is some sort of 'official' update? That is, is it likely we really have to wait years for this to get fixed, or...?

Comment: @Monomeeth yes it is official, the app developer mentioned few times already that he can't even fix bugs in the app due to the freeze set by management.

Comment: @ShadowtheHedgehogWizard That's a real shame, since it's a real pain and is probably not that hard to fix. Thanks for the fast response though! :) Much appreciated!

Comment: Will this app ever see bug fixes or updates?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Based on comments from January...doesn’t look like it. :(

Comment: reproduced. i inadvertently made an answer to a question instead of a comment under an answer. (i couldn’t delete the answer which i file a bug on) but having copied it could not paste the text into the comments field. the text pasted into other apps (though in the Notes app the text goes in not as inline text but as an unreadable “text block” which is a possible clue to failure here, but not if text from other apps is not pasting also.

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil Even text copied from Notes itself is sometimes pasted as an unreadable text block, so that might be an iOS bug, not an SE one. The rest certainly is an issue and has been for quite some time now.