# Future plans for the Stack Exchange iOS app beta version

Tags: support, ios-app

I’m using Stack Exchange iOS app 1.7.0.1 beta and it expires shortly:

> [image: beta]

Latest stable version in the AppStore is 1.6.6 was released about 4 months ago.

What are the future plans of Stack Exchange team about the iOS app?

Will we see new beta in the next week?

Comment: Related: [Can we have an updated beta (TestFlight) app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301656/307988) and [Are more ... features coming?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/307988)

Comment: @Cai first one looks like a duplicate, but I'm confusing about closing my post because answer is here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pestered Kasra in chat about this. Brian who works on the iOS app is out so we don't have exact dates/plans, but he is working on updates for iOS 11 and the iPhone X. That should include a new beta, but again, vacations/the weekend means I don't have specifics here.

TL;DR: Soon™

Comment: Sorry I'm confused. On one hand, Kasra himself clearly said "Brian and I are both slated to be full time on the DAG team for the foreseeable future". On the other hand, you claim Brian is still working on the iOS app. So what's really going on?

Comment: @shawizdoward As far as I understand it, updating the app for iOS 11 / the new iPhone is part of ongoing maintenance for the app. They aren’t working on new features, but are carving out time to keep it up to date.

Comment: So they don't work full time in DAG team, just giving hand for the DAG team whenever needed, but otherwise working on the "ongoing maintenance" for the iOS app? (Which also implies none of such work is done for the android app, aka that app is indeed as dead as it can be)

Comment: @shawizdoward Android app should be getting the same treatment if I understand correctly (it being late on a Friday I can’t really confirm). They are indeed not full time on DAG projects; I think it varies each month (which is the length of each planning cycle) depending on the balance of DAG’s needs vs mobile needs.

Comment: Well, that's semi-reassuring. Thanks! :)

Comment: Is there something I can do to help fixing bugs such as https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299803/137096 ? (it is annoying)

Comment: I hope Brian never gets hit by a train. It seems he is the only one capable of refreshing the app in Testflight. Why can't someone else update it so your testers can keep using it?

Comment: It would be great if accommodations were made to at least push out the same release again, if the beta is going to expire. I’m happy to test pre-release versions but it’s frustrating when they expire, and I have no app at all!

Comment: @miken32 Please go ahead and install the App Store version.  The iOS app isn't being actively developed at the moment.  Sorry for the trouble.